# Windows Form(desktop) application in .net core 3.0 preview for version is not running with .net core 3.0 run-time version

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a windows application in .net core 3.0 preview, when I publish it and run **on different machine**, it is **not working with** .net core 3.0 preview **run time version** on that machine
 As per my knowledge, sdk is for development and to run on other machine it only need .net core run time version.

In my case on other machine, it is **working** only **with**  .net core 3.0 preview **SDK but** not with .net core 3.0 preview run time.

This image describe problem, I have also tried this on new blank machine and found same issue.
[image]

Error :

```
It was not possigle to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App',version '3.0.0.-preview4-27613-28' was not found
  - No frameworks were found.
```

Can you please help/suggest me with this?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean `Windows application`? A desktop application, or an ASP.NET Core web app deployed to Windows? In any case, there's no information in the question. .NET Core 3 works, and only needs the runtime on the server.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.0 so I *know* the SDK isn't needed. Have you installed the *correct* runtime though? We are currently at 3.0 Preview 5. What does `dotnet --list-runtimes` return on the server? Have you tried publishind a *self-contained* web app? That will package and publish the runtime itself, so it won't matter what runtime is installed. You could even have different web apps running on different preview runtimes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  We have Windows Form desktop application

Comment: Can you post a minimal repeatable version of the code and setup? For instance, could you run `dotnet --list-sdks` on the machine with the SDK installed, and could you run `dotnet --list-runtimes` on the machine with the Runtime installed

Comment: @JeetBhatt in that case fix the tags and explain what you actually did, ie commands, parameters, installed runtimes

Comment: @JeetBhatt post the *text* not the screenshot. It's clear from the error message that the runtime versions are *not* the same. The program was built using an older version of the SDK. You can copy the text from a message box simply by hitting `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes in alert box it is different version but as you see in reality at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0 there is only one preview 4 version, and I have used those SDK and Runtime & Hosting Bundle

Comment: No there isn't just one version. .NET Core is still in Preview, this means not even a Beta. It changes daily and versions come out all the time and older builds are simply replaced. The error is clear anyway, you'll have to install the correct runtime version. You should probably upgrade to Preview 5 anyway instead of using the already abandoned Preview 4

Comment: To avoid this problem for now, you can publish a self-contained package. This publish the runtime itself in the application's folder. This means that each web app can use its own runtime version. The downside is that the web app's size increases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but i don't wan't to publish with self-contained package.

Comment: @JeetBhatt install the latest preview version then. You could update the Preview 4 SDK on your machine but there's no real point in using an old preview